# Download file from webdav server

Tags: http, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, webdev.webserver

My VBScript is as follows:

```
Dim myURL 
Dim password
Dim username 
myURL = "https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/d.txt" ' change your URL here...
username = "xyz@gmail.com"
password = "xyzpassword"

Dim HttpReq 
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
HttpReq.send
myURL = HttpReq.responseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile "C:\d.txt", 2 ' change your path here...
    oStrm.Close
End If
```

There is no error detected when I run it but the file is not downloaded on to my PC.

Comment: Use MsgBox to see whats going on inside your script

Answer (score 0):

> remove " from username and password.

```
Dim myURL 
Dim password
Dim username 
myURL = "https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/d.txt" ' change your URL here...
username = "xyz@gmail.com"
password = "xyzpassword"

Dim HttpReq 
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, username, password
HttpReq.send
myURL = HttpReq.responseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile "C:\d.txt", 2 ' change your path here...
    oStrm.Close
End If
```